# jquery css display menu (when open one close the others)

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I am designing a web page, my idea is to have 3 buttons on the top, and that if one of them click, display a dropdown menu below the buttons.
The problem I have is that not how to tell jquery in case there and a menu displayed, this is closed and I pressed open, and if I press the same as already deslegado, this is close.

I try it but doesn't work

```
$("#btn2").click(function (e) {
    if( $('.desplegable').css('display') == 'block' ) {
        $('.desplegable').slideUp(1000);    
    }

    $('#desplegable_right').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

I leave the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Bu5eX/

I've looked at other questions on Stackoverflow but I misunderstood / able to understand any example.
thank you very much

Comment: I try it but doesn't work

$("#btn_l2").click(function (e) {
    if( $('#desplegable_left').hasClass('desplegado') ){
  $('#desplegable_left').slideUp(1000);
  $('#desplegable_left').removeClass('desplegado');
    }else{ 
  $('.desplegable').slideUp(1000);    
  $('#desplegable_left').slideDown(1000);
  $('#desplegable_left').addClass('desplegado');
    }    
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Toggling Open/Close of a Sub-Panel

I would start with the following **HTML**:

```
<div class="button-wrap">
    <div id='btn1' class='button'>button1</div>
    <div id='btn2' class='button'>button2</div>
    <div id='btn3' class='button'>button3</div>
</div>
<div id='desplegable_left' class='desplegable btn1'>Left</div>
<div id='desplegable_center' class='desplegable btn2'>Center</div>
<div id='desplegable_right' class='desplegable btn3'>Right</div>
```

You want to link each `.button` element to a corresponding `.desplegable` element, and one way of doing it is to assign the `id` value of each `.button` as a class name to the corresponding `.desplegable` element.

For the **jQuery**, use the following:

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {
    var theID = $(this).attr("id");
    var theDisplay = $('.desplegable.' + theID).css("display");
    if (theDisplay == 'none') {
        $('.desplegable').hide();
        $('.desplegable.' + theID).slideToggle(1000);
    } else {
        $('.desplegable.' + theID).slideToggle(1000);
    }
});
```

When you click on `.button`, get the value of the `id` attribute.

You can then elect the corresponding target element by using the combined CSS selector, for example `.desplegable.btn1` and check the CSS `display` property value to see if it is either "none" or "block", which corresponds to hidden or displayed, respectively.

If the target element is hidden (`display: none`), then you hide all the target elements and open the one of interest.

Otherwise, simply toggle or hide the current one.

I am not sure if you really want the target element to appear to the right of the buttons and then shift down below the row of buttons.

You can fix that by adding `overflow: auto` to the parent, containing that wraps the buttons
as shown in the **CSS**:

```
.button-wrap {
    outline: 1px dotted blue; /* Optional! for demo only */
    overflow: auto; /* This will make sure the floats 
                       don't inteact with .desplegable div's */
}
```

The Fiddle Demo is at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/4FWMe/

Comment: I use it, thanx Marc but this solution don't close the opened div, just hide, when I try to close previous to open an other doesn't work

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to open div to close using `.slideToggle` instead of `.hide`?  I can take a look that later, there may be a trick to make sure the animation events don't fire simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#btn1").click(function (e) {
    $('.desplegable').hide();
    $('#desplegable_left').slideToggle(1000);
});
$("#btn2").click(function (e) {
     $('.desplegable').hide();
    $('#desplegable_center').slideToggle(1000);
});
$("#btn3").click(function (e) {
     $('.desplegable').hide();
    $('#desplegable_right').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu5eX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your selectors a bit:

```
// use one function for all buttons....
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    // i is current index of the clicked button, and curr
    // the current element.
    var i = $(this).index('.button'),
        curr = $('.desplegable').eq(i);
    // hide all elements (except the current element)
    $('.desplegable').not(curr).hide();
    // slide down the current one (this has only effect in case
    // the current one is invisible. Or in case you want to open
    // close the active one on click use slideToggle instead of slideDown
    curr.slideDown(1000);   
});
```

Updated [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/Bu5eX/5/).

Answer (score 1):

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Bu5eX/9/

Add targets to your buttons, and this small scripts will do all for your buttons.

*It will also close the menu opened.

## JQUERY

```
$('.button').click(function(){      
    var getID = $(this).attr('target');
    
    if($('#'+getID).css('display') != 'block'){
        $('.desplegable').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown(500);
    }
    else       
        $('.desplegable').slideUp(500);
});
```

Comment: but if i click in the same button, doesn't close the menu opened

Comment: +1 for using a custom attribute to connect button element to target element.

Comment: Pls check again the update code < jsfiddle.net/Bu5eX/9/ > Thanks Marc Audet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same selectors. When user click button you need o catch that button's index. then add too all div' 'desplegable' class 'will-remove' or somehing like this. Then delete this class(will-remove) from div with same index of clicked button. and then you know what to do:)

Comment: but when central is open and I click in an other don't close central and show the other